# VMware USB autoConnect blacklisting?

Tags: usb, vmware, vmware-workstation, blacklist

Is there a way to stop VMware (Workstation 12 Player) from automatically connecting a USB device?

When I wake up my Surface (Win 10 x64) it connects the Type Cover to the running Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.3, 4.3 kernel) guest, which doesn't seem to know how to handle it. I then have to use the touch screen to manually disconnect the device (= attach it to the Windows host) to be able to move my cursor or type again.

I'm sure there is an option to ignore a device in the .vmx config file...?

Edit: Note that I don't want to generally disable usb.autoConnect, because I need it for another device (an Arduino Micro that must be quickly reattached in bootloader mode...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either stop Mware USB Arbitration Service
or
try to uncheck "Automatically connect new USB devices" in "VM Setting ->USB controller panel" and check "do not show this hint again".

Comment: Completely disabling autoconnect is not a good option either :( I updated my question.